# LINQ Expression - Using .Any in s Select Could Not Be Translated

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Asp.net Core 3.1 LINQ Expression group by and select from a table and I use any into select but there is an error.

But it works fine in asp.net standard.

Code:

```
List<GetObj> liste = dbContext.testTable
          .Where(x => x.isActive == true).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
          .GroupBy(x => new { x.field1, x.field2 })
          .Select(x => new GetObj
          {
               field1 = x.Key.field1,
               field2 = x.Key.field2,
               totalQuantity = x.Sum(y => y.ldNet),
               isMaped = x.Any(y => y.isLastMove == true)
           }).ToList();
```

And the resulted error is:

> ```
> .Any(y => y.isLastMove == True)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
> ```

Comment: Is there any reason why `True` in the error is differently cased to `true` in the code?

Comment: No This has not any effect.

Comment: Hey, you can also make the query more efficient by implementing it using C# keywords like from, where , orderby, group by. Something like this:
`from table in dbContext.testTable
where table.isActive == true
orderby table.Id descedning
group new { table.ldNet, table.isLastMove } by new {table.field1, table.field2} into tableGrp
select new GetObj {
field1 = x.Key.field1,
field2 = x.Key.field2,
totalQuantity = tableGrp.Sum(x => x.ldNet),
isMaped = tableGrp.Max(x => x.isLastMove)
}`
if you are using orderby for different columns you can also put an index for it.

Answer (score 2):

Currently (EF Core 3.x) only projection of key / scalar aggregates is [supported for GroupBy queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby), and `Any` does not fall into that category.

A bit unusual and not so readable, but since `Any` returns `false` if all element conditions are `false`, and also `true > false`, `Any` can be replaced with the supported `Max` aggregate:

```
isMaped = x.Max(y => y.isLastMove)
```

Comment: Thank Ivan Stoev i got it, this way maybe not readable but so short , do you have any suggestions to solve this.

Comment: @sadullahzolfqar This *is* the solution of your original issue, what else suggestions do you need?